# How to retain functionality of X/Close button of shadcn Dialog when using the "open" prop of <Dialog> element?

Tags: reactjs, radix-ui

X/Close button of shadcn Dialog does not work if I use "open" prop of  element.

I don't see in shadcn or radix docs an event handler for the default X/close button (the one in top right).

I need to use the open prop to close the Dialog after an async operation has completed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `setOpen` to `onOpenChange` prop

e.g.

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

return <Dialog open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen} />
```

P.S This will also allow users to click outside the dialog to close it which may or may not be the wanted behavior

Comment: onOpenChange={setOpen}  did the trick! Thanks!